# Get data from array in object with function

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a function that returns the value of a variable inside an object like so :

```
public function getVar($var)
{
    return ($this->$var);
}
```

It works fine, but I cannot find a way to get the value of an array stored inside a variable. I thought something like this would work:

```
$object->getVar("variable['value']");
```

but it doesn't .... How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is not applicable to arrays. Use this instead:

```
public function getVar($var, $index = null)
{
    if (null === $index)
        return $this->$var;

    $var = $this->$var;
    return $var[$index];
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$yourClass = new YourClass();

$yourClass->array = array('a' => 'b');
$yourClass->someVar = 'c';

echo $yourClass->getVar('array', 'a'); // output: b
echo $yourClass->getVar('someVar'); // output: c
```